# DateTime being returned incorrectly from WCF; still shown correctly in Front-end

Tags: c#, wcf

We're deploying new servers to run our WCFs, and ran into an ... unusual problem in our *current*, 
production servers .

**TLDR**;

Something in our WCF and Front-end servers is making them shift `DateTime`s stored in databases *back* and *forth*. Please help me find out *what*.

---

We have a DateTime filled in a SQL Server 2016 table/column, like this:

(DataAgendamento stands for "Scheduling Date")

[image: Correct database value]

The stored procedure returns it correctly; WCF does not. For some odd reason, the value returned is an hour shifted *back*:
[image: Current WCF Server returning wrong value]

Things get weirder still: Our front-end application (running ASP.NET WebForms in .NET Framework 4.0) receives this value from the WCF and... adds an hour back. So, in the end, we have the value "correctly" 
displayed.

[image: "Correct" value displayed]

**None of the projects, WCF or Front end have an `.AddHour` in the code.** Checked a few times.

A few remarks:

1. Both WCF and Front-end are currently running in different Windows Server 2016 physical machines.
2. Both IIS have a Portuguese-BR globalization setting.
3. Stored procedures are executed in the WCF layer, and fully returned as `DataTable`s. Its data does not face any kind of conversion, parsing, `ToString`*ing* whatsoever in WCF. Front-end does that, but the values are wrong before such treatments are in effect.
4. Not sure if related: For the first time in thirty five years, we're going to face a summer *without* our usual Daylight Saving Time Schedule (which usually runs from november to mid-february).
5. This behavior has been spotted in several, different methods (and procedures).
6. The code to display the DateTime is `Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow[0]["DataAgendamentoFinal"]).ToString("mm")` in the image above.
7. This bug/not-bug scenario works *now*, but new WCF servers do not have this setting (whichever it is) enabled, so it returns `DateTime` (actually) correctly, only to have an hour added to the result in front-end.
8. Database, WCF and Front-end servers are running in the same timezone (GMT-3 Brasilia) (Thanks, @Sooryan). This timezone does not consider DST.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your DB server and Client server have same timezone while WCF server is having a timezone difference of 1 hour.

Comment: ... Forgot to remark that as well @Sooryan. Checked that. The three servers are running in GMT-3 (Brasilia) timezone.

Answer (score 0):

When WCF is called across time zones (WCF server-side and client-side are not in the same time zone), WCF automatically converts the time fetched from the server to the local time of the client. As a distributed framework, it is sensible that WCF do this conversion. But sometimes the business logic may not need such time conversion, we can change the DateTime field to string(convert to string on the server-side), which can avoid the problem of time automatic conversion. Or use UTC time. Here are some discussions on this subject.
[WCF converting time based on timezone automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356384/wcf-converting-time-based-on-timezone-automatically)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36ae825a-ffc6-4ac3-9981-c82692039d58/wcf-is-translating-my-datetime-values-across-different-time-zones?forum=wcf
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a63d0409-a8ec-4a83-8c82-f6c39356d96e/disabling-automatic-time-conversion-in-wcf?forum=wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: This assumes that the servers (WCF and front-end) are not in the same timezone. That is not the case; Both run on GMT-3.  That being said, we had some issues regarding the DST last year, and ended up tinkering up with the Automatic DST radio. Think that might have had an impact?

Comment: Em, seems you are right. To exclude this factor, we could attempt to convert the DateTime data to string field, then verify the result.